# Removing data from one dataframe that exists in another dataframe R

Tags: r

I want to remove data from a dataframe that is present in another dataframe. Let me give an example:

```
letters<-c('a','b','c','d','e')
numbers<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
list_one<-data.frame(letters,numbers)
```

I want to remove every row in list_one with matches in letters to this other dataframe:

```
letters2<-c('a','c','d')
list_two<-data.frame(letters2)
```

I should mention that I'm actually trying to do this with two large csv files, so I really can't use the negative expression - to take out the rows.

And create a final dataframe which only has the letters b and e and their corresponding numbers. How do I do this?

I'm new to R so it's hard to research questions when I'm not quite sure what key terms to search. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Fyi, `letters` is actually a constant/built-in vector, as is `LETTERS`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base R Solution

```
list_one[!list_one$letters %in% list_two$letters2,]
```

gives you:

```
  letters numbers
2       b       2
5       e       5
```

Explanation:

```
> list_one$letters %in% list_two$letters2
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This gives you a vector of `LENGTH == length(list_one$letters)` with TRUE/FALSE Values. `!` negates this vector. So you end up with FALSE/TRUE values if the value is present in *list_two$letters2*.

If you have questions about how to select rows from a data.frame enter

```
?`[.data.frame`
```

to the console and read it.

Answer (score 9):

A dplyr solution

```
library(dplyr)

list_one %>% anti_join(list_two)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is response to your edit:
" so I really can't use the negative expression".

I guess one of the most efficient ways to do this is using `data.table` as follows:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(list_one)
setDT(list_two)
list_one[!list_two, on=c(letters = "letters2")]
```

Or

```
require(data.table)
setDT(list_one, key = "letters")
setDT(list_two, key = "letters2")
list_one[!letters2]
```

(Thanks to Frank for the improvement)

Result:

```
   letters numbers
1:       b       2
2:       e       5
```

Have a look at `?"data.table"` and [Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r#answer-15058684) on why to use `data.table::fread`to read the csv-files in the first place.

BTW: If you have `letters2` instead of `list_two` you can use

```
list_one[!J(letters2)]
```